# Why Maximum value for tinyint(1) is being shown as 1 in cakephp 2.10?

Tags: mysql, cakephp

I have a field named 'day' of tinyint(1) in holiday table. So I am able to add any value in -128 to 127 range. I can do it by running raw sql inside phpmyadmin as follows:

```
INSERT INTO `holidays`( `day`) VALUES (5)
```

But when I try to save it using cakephp as follows:

```
$this->Holiday->save($this->request->data);
```

1 is being saved in 'day' field. But value of 'day' inside `$this->request->data` is 5. Here is the full array just before `$this->Holiday->save();` line:

```
Array
(
    [Holiday] => Array
        (
            [title] => weekend
            [holiday_year] => 2017
            [holiday_type] => 1
            [holiday_start_date] => 
            [holiday_end_date] => 
            [day] => 5
            [institute_id] => 1
            [created_by] => 9
            [created_date] => 1506580580
            [terminal] => ::1
            [status] => 1
        )
)
```

When I changed tinyint(1) to tinyint(4) then 5 is being saved as 5. But why cakephp save 5 as 1 for tinyint(1) while raw sql save 5 as 5 for tinyint(1).